# How to Terminate a App on a custom Case. iOS4

Tags: iphone

My App needs a Internet Connection which is checkt in the ViewDidLoad if there is no Internet connection I want to terminate the app when the Home Button is clickt so that  the app start in its initial state next time but only in this case.
If there is a Internet connection from the start the homeButton should bring the app just to the background.

Comment: This will get your app rejected by Apple.

Comment: are you sure about that....
it would make the solution of my problem much easier but its not this good....
thanks for telling me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does strongly discourages quitting from application programmatically.

I think you can handle your case without quitting application - when application goes to background(in applicationDidEnterBackground method of application delegate) save some flag indicating that you want to reinit it on resume, then when application comes back to foreground (applicationWillEnterForeground method in delegate) apply your initialization logic in case flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically terminate an App is a behaviour that will be rejected to be published in the AppStore, as it seems that the application crashed.

If you don't mind that your application will never see the light at the AppStore, you can simply use exit(0).

Comment: You can legally terminate an app by setting the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend plist key, and then launching Safari by URL (a well documented API).  When Safari starts, your app's terminate delegate will be called and then your app's process will be killed.

This will not be rejected by Apple (unless for some other reason), as many apps call Safari.

However there is no way to make the exit on suspend decision at run-time.

Comment: You can use `exit(0)` if you notify the user that you're closing first, i.e. via a `UIAlertView`. Something like "This app can't run because there's no Intertrons." with a "Quit" button. In other words, you can kill your app so long as it's clear *why*.

Comment: Forgot to say, there's another way to quit the application (that won't be approved neither):

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];

Answer (score 0):

When your app does not find an internet connection, switch to a view that exactly imitates your Default start-up image, then force that view to stay visible the usual amount of start-up time after any call to making your app active.  You can also kill and recreate fresh all your other MVC objects during this time.

That way, no one will know that your app wasn't freshly started when brought back from the background.